# Match against property in array of objects without using For loop

Tags: java

I have an array of objects `TimeTrial`.  Each TimeTrial object contains the time to run the trial, the distance, and the person who ran it.

Given a person, I want to see whether the person has run any of the trials in the list.  If the list was just a list of people, I would write `trials.contains(person)`.

In Python, I would just do `if person in map(lambda trial: trial["runner"], trials)`.  But this functionality doesn't seem too be available in Java.

Is there a simple way to do this without writing a For loop?

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: why the requirement to not use the most appropriate thing? you realize that `map` and equivlent methods iterate under the covers right? same difference, syntactic sugar not withstanding

Comment: No way this is a duplicate -.-
He wants something close to lambda expressions.. in this case, filter. The other topic you're referencing as duplicate is something else (sorting).

Comment: Use this:

List<TimeTrial> timeTrials = ...

Stream<Person> timeTrialsPersonHasRan = timeTrials.stream().filter(t -> t.wasRanBy(personId));

Comment: @BrenoInojosa why not provide this as an answer?

Comment: @Farhad : because this topic is now closed T.T

Comment: Use a List and the `contains` method.  Or, if one insists on using a vanilla array, write a recursive method.

Comment: Well, anyway, I posted my answer there, in the other topic.